# Changing pandas dataframe values from list to string

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe where most of values are stored as list. That is unnecessary to me. I would like to convert those list into their first(and only member). That is to say, I would like to value = value[0]. 
But this does not work

All in all:
How to "unlist" all values in dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you can use [`.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas.DataFrame.applymap). Something like:

```
>>> unlist = lambda l: l[0] if len(l) != 0 else None
>>> unwrap = lambda l: unlist(l) if isinstance(l, list) else l
>>> df.applymap(unwrap)
```